# Подскажите эти файлы относятся к системе или вирус?

Tags: linux, вирусы

Онаружил в корне своего сайта странные файлы: 
init c таким содержанием https://pastein.ru/t/-e
и 
perl_modules.conf
со строкой

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB '/nix/store/jcn8d3r3rc0zhi3r7p3z68xqc82cjh4p-perl-5.20.3/lib/perl5:/nix/store/vb9bmq49h7g572zzx4c40hl2wd978g3a-perl-union/lib/perl5/site_perl:.:.'
```

perl_modules_modperl.conf

```
PerlSetEnv PERL5LIB '/nix/store/jcn8d3r3rc0zhi3r7p3z68xqc82cjh4p-perl-5.20.3/lib/perl5:/nix/store/vb9bmq49h7g572zzx4c40hl2wd978g3a-perl-union/lib/perl5/site_perl:.:.'
```

Подскажите это нормальные файлы системы или подозрение на вирус ?

Comment: к программе linux они точно не имеют отношения.

Comment: Подозрительные весьма.

Comment: Очень похоже на то что вам шелл подсадили.

Answer (score 2):

(**Ubuntu**)

Как пример , когда свежая база находил пару раз "exploit*"

```
sudo apt install clamav clamav-daemon

sudo freshclam ----Обнови базу

sudo clamscan -r /nix/store/*
```